# How does externalize know when to redraw a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am learning about the externalization library (manual version 3.1.3, section 52, page 661). There isn't anything mentioned regarding how the library redraws/regenerates a modified `tikzpicture`. In other words, what triggers the need to redraw a `tikzpicture` again?

The documentation stated the following:

> Filenames are generated automatically in the default configuration. In
>   our case, the two file names will be *main-figure0* and
>   *main-figure1*. If they exist, those images are simply included and the pictures as such are not processed. If graphics files do not
>   exist, steps are taken to generate the missing ones.

Comment: I did not check but would imagine it uses `\pgfutil@IfFileExists`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a file named `main-figure0.md5`. I am not sure but I think it is the Hash of your entire tikzpicture, so if you change anything inside your graph description, the new hash differs from the old one an triggers the redrawing.

Comment: Okay, how would it find the hash value to compare with previously calculated ones without calculating it first (i.e., without redrawing it again)?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily it doesn't have to redraw it, it is enough to store the hash of the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! You made it more clearer!